# FragmentActivity generated integer resources are large integers

Tags: android, android-resources, android-fragmentactivity, r.java-file

I have used a constant

```
private int SOME_GEN_ID = 1;
startActivityForResult(intent , SOME_GEN_ID);
```

instead of using a integer defined in /res/values/integers.xml as an argument to `startActivtyForResult()`

```
startActivityForResult(intent , R.integer.some_gen_id);
```

By using a constant, it has resolved the error:

```
"Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode"
```

However, I was wondering if this issue has been resolved, or are all integer resources resolved to large integers when using a `FragmentActivty`?

Original Issue reported [HERE](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=958)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`R.integer.some_gen_id` is not the value of an integer resource. It is an *ID* of an integer resource. IDs are 32-bit values. If you want the *value* of an integer resource, use `getResources().getInteger(R.integer.some_gen_id)`.

Comment: According to tools.android.com/recent/buildchangesinrevision14 "Generating IDs as non final in the library projects, means that the library code cannot treat these IDs as constants. This means, for example, that you can’t use res IDs in a switch statement." I guess this is why i got the error: 'case expressions must be constant expressions' when i grabbed the value of the integer resource getResources().getInteger(R.integer.some_gen_id) and attempted to use that value in a switch statement within the onActivityResult() method.

Comment: @toobsco42: Correct. Either use Java `static final` values or use `if()` instead of `switch()`.

Comment: It's a bit misleading to say that you can't use res IDs in switch statements, isn't it? - e.g. in a method specified by the `onClick` attribute of a `View`, you can use the res IDs in a switch statement to match the passed `View` with an expected `View` case.

Comment: @ataulm: Bear in mind that the OP is referring to a library project. The rules there differ than for regular apps.